# Hard Coding date_default_timezone_get()

Tags: database

I am getting this error when I transferred my ee site to a new host:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'GMT/0.0/no DST' instead
Filename: libraries/Core.php
Line Number: 227
```

Unfortunately in my current hosting solution we are not allowed to adjust the php.ini file and the date setting are set to UTC on the server. I was wondering if there was a way to set this function to be UTC without trying to grab the result from the PHP.ini form.

Because of the nature of the site and the company, I don't have the option to move to a new host or to request this change to PHP.ini.

Thanks for any help you can offer. My version of Expression Engine is v2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try doing that in your .htaccess file, in the root of your site?

```
php_value date.timezone 'Europe/London'
```

You should also be able to edit that core EE file, like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

But doing it in .htaccess will ensure it updates the whole application.

Solution found [here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread469.html). [Here are all the timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) that are supported.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  This should work but I have to wait for my administrator to turn on rewrite rules for the server.  It did work on my local machine though, so thanks!